# Build a Flatten layer to work with layers that have variable input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I have this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(None, None, 1), strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

It will generate the following error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

I want to make a new layer that will be able to build a flatten tensor from tensors with variable shape  `(None, None, 1)`.

I tried to build a new layer like the following:

```
class MyFlattenLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, data_format=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyFlattenLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=1)
        self._channels_first = self.data_format == 'channels_first'
        

    def call(self, inputs):
        shape = K.shape(inputs)
        batchSize = shape[:1]
        newShape = K.variable([-1],dtype='int32')
        newShape = K.concatenate([batchSize,newShape])
        return K.reshape(inputs,newShape)
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        batchSize = input_shape[:1]
        newShape = K.variable([-1],dtype='int32')
        newShape = K.concatenate([batchSize,newShape])
        
        return tensor_shape.TensorShape(newShape)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MyFlattenLayer, self).get_config()
        config.update({'data_format': self.data_format})
        return config

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(None, None, 1), strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(MyFlattenLayer())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

But this also generates another error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

How to build a Flatten layer to work with layers that have variable input shape ?

**UPDATE**

I was able to build a MyFlattenLayer for variable dimension of input for first Conv2D layer. It compiles without errors, and I can even train and predict just for testing. But something looks strange, like when I try to show summary of the model and count parameters, and even when I try to display all tensors values for all layers, then values of MyFlattenLayer are missing...and not displayed, however it is able to use compile, train and predict functions, How if it is missing some parameters? I understand that Dense layer must have a constant dimension of input, but still looking to find a workaround or something that will help to achive something similar not necessarily the same.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import conv_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape

from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops


class MyFlattenLayer(Flatten):

  def __init__(self, data_format=None, **kwargs):
    super(MyFlattenLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=1)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
    if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
      return tensor_shape.TensorShape([input_shape[0], input_shape[3]])
    else:
      return tensor_shape.TensorShape([input_shape[0], input_shape[1]])

  def call(self, inputs):
    tens = backend.flatten(inputs)
    threshold = tf.constant(-99999999, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(inputs < threshold, dtype=tf.float32)
    if tens.shape[0] == None:
      tens = array_ops.reshape(inputs, (y.shape[3],1)) 
      return tens
    else:
      tens = array_ops.reshape(inputs, (tens.shape[0],1)) #backend.reshape(tens, (tens.shape[0],1)) 
      
      return tens
    

  def get_config(self):
    config = {'data_format': self.data_format}
    base_config = super(MyFlattenLayer, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(None, None, 1), strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add( MyFlattenLayer() )
# model.add( Flatten() )
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.00006)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer)
x = np.arange(0, 25).reshape(1, 5, 5, 1).astype(np.float32)
out = model.train_on_batch(x, np.array([[1, 0]]))
print("results: \n", out , "\n\n")
for layer in model.layers: print(layer.get_config(), layer.get_weights())
```

This also works:

```
x = np.arange(0, 25*35).reshape(1, 25, 35, 1).astype(np.float32)
out = model.train_on_batch(x, np.array([[1, 0]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the Flatten operation does not work, it theoretically should work for variable shapes as far as I am concerned. The problem is, that you try to feed the flattened output into a dense layer, which needs to know how many weights it has. The number of weights does directly depend on the input shape (more precisely on the last dimension of it, since the dense layer is applied to this dimension), so feeding a variable shaped input into the dense layer does not work.

Comment: But how to build a new dense layer class that will count flattened output and set it as input dimension, this is possible ?

Comment: This will not work since every dense layer needs to know what its input shape is. Just think of it as follows: Treat every input element as a neuron (so if the input has length 10 then we think of it as 10 neurons). Then, we connect these neurons to out dense layer. If this has 10 neurons as well, then we will have 100 connection weights, because all of the 10 input neurons are connected to all of the 10 dense layer neurons. But now imagine that the neural network does not know how many input neurons there are. How is it supposed to know how many weights it needs?

Comment: And if the input dimensionality changes over time, then what do you expect the dense layer to do? Do you expect it to have a different number of weights depending on the input dimensionality? This does not work as well. So you need to rethink the way you want to set up your network. If you briefly outline your problem I might be able to give you a suggestion on how to build a suitable model.

Comment: I was able to build a FlattenLayer for variable dimension of input for first Conv2D layer. It compiles without errors, and I can even train and predict. But something looks strange, like when I try to show summary of the model and count parameters, and even when I try to show all tensors values for all layers, then values of FlattenLayer are missing.... so how it compiles, trains and predict if it is missing ? .. I will update my post later with code update

Comment: As I mentioned above: A flatten layer for variable shape inputs does not work if you want to follow it by a dense layer!! And by saying this I do not mean that there is no tensorflow implementation of it, but that it is literally impossible (for the reasons described earlier).

Comment: Now to what you did: You reshaped the input to your custom layer in some way, and then you added another dimension at the end, so that your output then has shape (x, 1) instead of just shape (x,). If you now feed this input to your dense layer, then tensorflow applies this dense layer to the last dimension of your input, which means that the dense layer is applied to every element individually. If your input shape was (x, 1), then your output shape then will be (x, 2), because your dense layer is applied to every single element of these x elements and has 2 output values per dense layer call.

Comment: If you briefly describe what you want to achieve with your network, I might be able to give you a hint on what you can try, but your current approach with applying the dense layer on the flattened input will certainly not work.